# xtify return me code 3000

Tags: iphone, xtify

I am trying to use xtify push with production certificate and adhoc provisining but when I am running sample of xtify after setting up proper certificate and try to install application it is showing the code 3000 error in console as shown below:-

```
2012-06-04 11:17:40.133 SampleRich[4945:707] Attempt to register for push notifications...
2012-06-04 11:17:40.147 SampleRich[4945:707] Device currentDevice.systemVersion=5.100000
2012-06-04 11:17:40.151 SampleRich[4945:707] __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=50100
2012-06-04 11:17:40.413 SampleRich[4945:707] Application moved from inactive to Active state
2012-06-04 11:17:40.507 SampleRich[4945:707] Failed to register with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x17cfe0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
2012-06-04 11:18:05.134 SampleRich[4945:707] *** ERROR *** App key not set yet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"**

You haven't enabled push for the app, or you haven't signed the app with the push enabled certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying it out with a development certificate and then move to the production one. As WrightsCS says, you need to sign the app with the correct push enabled certificates. The error is not from Xtify, it is from Apple.

[This](http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/1.+Register+your+iOS+application+with+Apple) has the instructions to help you with the push certificates. Let me know if you have more issues.